# Question about writing my own system call in FreeBSD

Tags: freebsd, kernel, system-calls

OK, so I just finish reading the implementation of kill(2) of FreeBSD, and am trying to write my own "kill". This system call takes `uid` and `signum` and sends the signal to processes owned by uid, excluding the calling process.

How can I pass `uid` to the system call? In kill(2), `pid` is in argument `struct kill_args`. Is there a structure that contains `uid` the way that `struct kill_args` contains `pid`? If not, can I define a structure outside the kernel?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It's easy, but kind of an involved process. Here's a module that installs a system call.

#### Include a bunch of stuff

```
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/param.h>
#include <sys/proc.h>
#include <sys/module.h>
#include <sys/sysent.h>
#include <sys/kernel.h>
#include <sys/systm.h>
#include <sys/sysproto.h>
```

#### Define your structure to hold arguments

```
struct mykill_args {
    int pid;
    int signo;
};
```

#### Define a handling function

```
static int
mykill(struct thread *td, void *args)
{
    struct mykill_args *uap = args;

    uprintf("mykill called. pid=%d, signo=%d\n", uap->pid, uap->signo);

    return 0;
}
```

#### You need a sysent object

```
static struct sysent mykill_sysent = {
    2,          /* number of arguments */
    mykill      /* function handling system call */
};
```

#### And an offset at which the system call will be installed.

```
/* Choose "the next" value later. */
static int offset = NO_SYSCALL;
```

#### `load` function

```
static int
load(struct module *module, int cmd, void *arg)
{
    int error = 0;

    switch (cmd) {
        case MOD_LOAD:
            uprintf("Loading module. Installing syscall at"
                " offset %d\n", offset);
            break;
        case MOD_UNLOAD:
            uprintf("Unloading module. syscall uninstalled from"
                " offset %d\n", offset);
            break;
        default:
            error = EOPNOTSUPP;
            break;
    }

    return error;
}
```

#### Install the system call

```
SYSCALL_MODULE(mykill, &offset, &mykill_sysent, load, NULL);
```

You can run your system call using `syscall(2)`. Or using perl :)). Here's an example

```
[root@aiur /home/cnicutar/kld-syscall]# kldload ./mykill.ko
Loading module. Installing syscall at offset 210

[cnicutar@aiur ~/kld-syscall]$ perl -e 'syscall(210, 30, 15);'
mykill called. pid=30, signo=15
```