# write a kld in FreeBSD

Tags: freebsd

I'm writing a new KLD in FreeBSD. 
I have a C file like this: 
[Question about writing my own system call in FreeBSD](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6542650/question-about-writing-my-own-system-call-in-freebsd) -- but my code's functionality is a bit different. I'm initializing a variable in kernelspace and my function name is `my_KLD`.

I can load it without problem with "kldload", but I have a problem: I'm going to use this kld through another C file.

The file structure is like this:

```c
int
main(int argc, char **argv)
{

 f ( atoi(argv[1]) ;

}

f ( int x) { 
       printf("hi\n");
       int syscall_num ; 
       struct module_stat stat ; 
       stat.version = sizeof(stat) ;
       modstat (modfind("my_KLD") , &stat) ; 
       syscall_num = stat.data.intval ; 
       return syscall (syscall_num , x ) ;
}
```

But when I call this file with argument x
the result is :

```
hi 
Bad System call (core dumped)
```

What else should I do?

Comment: In your sample code you are not checking the result of the modstat() call. It could be failing in some interesting ways -- you should check its result and call err() if it is anything but 0. The error-message, if any, may help you figure things out.

Answer (score 1):

In addition to the comment from Srh BlueOcean, you should also check the value returned by modfind(). You're assuming it can find your KLD and that's a big assumption. The KLD may not be loaded for whatever reason.

I find smaller steps are better, so call modfind and print out the integer ID to see if it is positive or negative (-1 is an error).

Something like this:

```
int modid;

if ((modid = modfind("my_KLD")) < 0) {
    perror("modfind failed");
    exit(1);
}
if (modstat(modid, &stat) < 0) {
    perror("modstat failed");
    exit(1);
}
```

The perror() function will provide you with an error message and you can check the man-page to determine what caused the error. For example, ENOENT is "The module was not found (probably not loaded)."