# load module in system call implementation

Tags: operating-system, freebsd, system-calls

I've seen some examples of adding system call to FreeBSD, as I understood , we should have a `load` module in the body of our implementation, and also this load is the same in every example which I've seen.
is the load module fix? if not, how can I implement it?

the following links are the examples of having the same load module:

1-[the link which answers about the system call implementation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6542650/question-about-writing-my-own-system-call-in-freebsd)

2- there is an example of system call here:  `/usr/share/examples/kld/syscall/module/syscall.c`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because of [this](http://www.freenix.no/arkiv/daemonnews/200010/blueprints.html) I understand that if I want to add a system call using Kernel Loadable, a load handler module is the same in all of KLD.

> "Basically, the load handler function is, as it states, a function
>   that handles the loading and unloading of a KLD. Hence, when a KLD is
>   kldloaded or kldunloaded, this handler is what, at a very simplistic
>   level, gets called."